# How to prevent drag selection highlight on canvas?

Tags: canvas, selection

I have a canvas element, when I do drag selection at canvas, there's a highlight selection box, see screenshot:

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: A highlight box is not the natural result of dragging in a canvas element. Are you sure you're working with a canvas element? Anyway, please show the offending code so we can check it out with you.

Comment: @markE Thank you very much. I use fabric.js, it's a feature of library, I just set `canvas.selection = false` solved the issue. I think I am a little bit stupid. :)